# Shared variables between thread and UI C#

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading

Can I safely share this "status" object between the two threads?

```
    private bool status = false;

    private void uiNewThread_bootloaderStartIdSetupAuto()
    {
        while (status)
            ;
    }
```

Above is the new thread that will be launched from UI below:

```
    private void uiBtnBootloaderStartIdSetupAuto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("ID will be setup starting from 1 to 16. \n\nAfter pressing 'YES', press the orange button one-by-one on the nodes.\nThe first pressed node will have number 1, the next number 2, and so on... \n\nWhen done, hit DONE button.", "ID setup", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            status = true;
            Thread transmitConfig = new Thread(new ThreadStart(uiNewThread_bootloaderStartIdSetupAuto)); //close port in new thread to avoid 
            transmitConfig.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            Log(LogMsgType.Normal, "User cancelled");
            status = false;            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Optimizations such as caching or reorderings done by the compiler or CPU could break your code. You should declare the field `volatile` to prevent this:

```
private volatile bool status = false;
```

An example of what could go wrong is that if the two threads are running on different cores, the value of `status` could be cached in a CPU register by the core where the polling thread is running, thus never seeing the value updated by the other thread.

Try to build your app in Release mode and you should see this effect.

Comment: In most cpu architectures and the .net framework, volatile is more or less redundant. Joe Duffy discusses here. http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2010/12/04/SayonaraVolatile.aspx

Comment: @stevethethread: On my system I have recreated this scenario countless times and obtained a deadlock in .NET. The problem here is very real.

Comment: Sadly even if it's right that normally by using `volatile` everything works, a `volatile write` doesn't guarantee that the write will ever be done before the heat death of the universe :-)

Comment: @xanatos: Actually here you need `volatile` for the read, since writes are volatile in .NET even without the keyword.

Comment: Use of the Volatile key word is merely to prevent re-ordering of memory read/writes, and most modern cpu architectures already enforce this, as does the .net framework.  The key thing about marking a variable volatile is that all read and writes to that variable are volatile, which may be overkill, so performance is not great.  If only relevant in one place, a simple lock would suffice.

Comment: @Tudor The point was that `volatile` doesn't guarantee the write, and without a write guarantee there can't be a read guarantee.

Comment: @stevethethread: This is more about preventing caching than reorders. Locks are much more heavyweight than volatile, since they you pay lock-unlock overheads and potentially context switches.

Comment: @Tudor, the caching you refer to is affected by code re-ordering that a compiler might do. Volatile does this. It is a memory buffer preventing code read/write re-ordering.  MSDN doco: Volatile memory operations are for special cases of synchronization, where normal locking is not an acceptable alternative. Under normal circumstances, the C# lock statement, the Visual Basic SyncLock statement, and the Monitor class provide the easiest and least error-prone way of synchronizing access to data.

Comment: Modern CPU's ensure that all caches are correctly updated, so the volatile keyword is mostly redundant.  Joe Duffy covers this really nicely in his book Concurrent Programming on Windows. Buy hey, I think we'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @stevethethread: Basically what I don't agree with is the necessity for a full lock here, since volatile provides the needed fences anyway, without the added overheads of locks.

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off simply locking on the variable e.g.

```
private static readonly object _lock = new Object();

....

lock(_lock){
//access to boolean variable etc.
}
```

Another possibility is to wrap the bool in a Lazy and access to the inner value is thread safe.

If you want to use lock free mechanisms for reading and updating the value, you can think about using methods from the Interlocked class.

Info here:

[System.Threading.Interlocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx)